# How to calculate throughput using JIRA?

Tags: jira, agile

There is requirement where we have to calculate the throughput for the agile train teams. Is there any chart in JIRA using which we can calculate throughput for agile train teams.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the data quality in Jira round this can be a problem.

~ With a budget: Actionable Agile makes a great plugin that cleans it up. But there'd be a cost of course. https://www.55degrees.se/actionableagile

~ Without: Troy Megennis of Focused Objective is a writer and speaker who specializes in Coaching With Data. You could try his downloadable dashboard (requires Excel)
https://www.focusedobjective.com/w/support/
It also does Monte Carlo simulations

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest thing to this is the [control chart](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-and-understand-the-control-chart/).

It will show you the rolling average of the mean time it takes for items to pass through your team's workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This script might be really useful for you: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/automatically-import-jira-backlog-into-google-spreadsheet

It's a script that connects a Google Spreadsheet to Jira, bringing all the details related to your cards, so you can easily calculate throughput, lead time, flow efficiency, whatever the metrics you want.